# UTF-8 string size in bytes

Tags: c, utf-8

I need to determine the length of UTF-8 string in bytes in C. How to do it correctly? As I know, in UTF-8 terminal symbol has 1-byte size. Can I use **strlen** function for this?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't define how strings are terminated. The use of the null character `'\0'` to terminate a string is a C convention.

Comment: The whole point of UTF-8 is that you don't have to change **any** of your string-processing practices. Only code that interprets the characters of a string potentially needs changing, and even then, usually only if it's applying special interpretation to characters outside of the ASCII range. Things like `strlen`, `strstr`, `strchr` (for searching for single-byte characters), `snprintf`, etc. just work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I use strlen function for this?

Yes, `strlen` gives you the number of bytes before the first `'\0'` character, so

```
strlen(utf8) + 1
```

is the number of bytes in `utf8` including the 0-terminator, since no character other than `'\0'` contains a 0 byte in UTF-8.

Of course, that only works if `utf8` is actually UTF-8 encoded, otherwise you need to convert it to UTF-8 first.

Comment: @JoopEggen: No, Latin-1 and high control characters are not single-byte in UTF-8. The **only** single-byte characters in UTF-8 are ASCII. In any case, the encoding is irrelevant to measuring the size of a string in bytes.

Comment: @R.. right; in fact I wanted just to mention the nicety of UTF-8 that the entire 7 bits ASCII range cannot erroneously found in UTF-8 multi-byte sequences because of the high bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, strlen() will simply count the bytes until it encounters the NUL, which is the correct terminator for a 0-terminated UTF-8-encoded C string.